# jQuery Custom Gallery and jCarousel problem

Tags: jquery, jcarousel

Active site can be seen here: http://www.studioimbrue.com/index2.php

There are currently two small problems with the coding. First: when the page loads and you attempt to click on one of the large images to advance, nothing happens. Once a thumbnail is clicked, the click functionality of the large image comes available. I'm trying to fix it so when the page loads, the user can just start clicking the large image.

Second: when an image is clicked, the thumbnail highlight changes. The only problem there is once it gets past 4, the "current" thumbnail needs to be seen, thus the carousel should go to that one. Right now the code for that is `nextThumb.closest('.thumbscontainer').jcarousel('next');` but that makes it scroll every time you click. Thanks for any help

Comment: You couldn't be more right. I'm in the process, but it's slow as I'm still in grad school and am always busy with school stuff. I'm sending my portfolio off soon so I just need to get the site perfect. Then when I have a job I'll actually have time of my own to spend learning the wondrous world of jquery :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You put the `$('.container .captions li').click(...)` code inside the thumbnails' click handler, so the click event for the full image is only added after the first thumbnail is clicked.

You should put that block (including its closing `});`) outside the other `click` handler.

Also, you should change

```
var nextThumb = nextLi
    .closest('.thumbscontainer')
    .find('.thumbscontainer li:eq(' + nextLi.index() + ')');
```

to `.closest('.container')`.

Comment: Perfect. Now I just need to figure out how to get the thumbnails to scroll properly. I obviously don't really know much about jQuery, but I don't think it's even possible because they are operating separately...